# Use StreamReader with HttpWebResponse block ReadToEnd()

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, windows-mobile, compact-framework, streamreader

I have a CSharp Application (CF2.0) for Windows Mobile 6.5 terminals.
I have a Thread that every 1.5 minutes try to connect to a PHP WebService. I try to read the response of this PHP WebService with a ReadToEnd() method.
It works, but sometimes (randomly) the routine blocks on ReadToEnd(). I don't know why.

This is the code:

```
public static string CallWebServiceProblem(string url, int timeout)
{

    string s = "";

    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;


    _logger.Trace("web service: {0} timeout: {1}", url, timeout);
    HttpWebRequest wrGETURL = null;
    try
    {
        bool isProblema = url.IndexOf("lsp_r2") >= 0;
        if (isProblema)
            _logger.Info("Sono in lsp_r2...");

        wrGETURL = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wrGETURL.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        wrGETURL.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000; // Per vedere se sistema un po' i timeout...
        if (timeout != 0)
            wrGETURL.Timeout = 3000; // timeout...

        Stream ojstream = null;
        StreamReader sr = null;
        HttpWebResponse httpresponse = null;

        try
        {
            if (isProblema)
                _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Chiamo GetResponse...");

            httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrGETURL.GetResponse();

            if (isProblema)
                _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Chiamo GetResponseStream...");

            ojstream = httpresponse.GetResponseStream();
            Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

            if (isProblema)
                _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Chiamo StreamReader...");

            sr = new StreamReader(ojstream, encode);

            if (isProblema)
                _logger.Info("lsp_r2: inizio a leggere");

            s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (isProblema)
            {
                _logger.Info("lsp_r2: terminato di leggere " + s.Length + " caratteri");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lsp_r2: terminato di leggere " + s.Length + " caratteri");
#if DEBUG
               // _logger.Info("lsp_r2: ho letto " + s);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lsp_r2: ho letto " + s);
#endif
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("web service: {0} timeout: {1} exception: {2} - {3}", url, timeout, ex.Message, ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "??");
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            if (isProblema)
                _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Concludo...");

            if (sr != null)
            {
                sr.Close();
                sr.Dispose();
            }

            if (ojstream != null)
            {
                ojstream.Close();
                ojstream.Dispose();
            }

            if (httpresponse != null)
            {
                httpresponse.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return s;

}
```

I use this routine for some PHP WS in my Application, but I have the problem only with one that returns a lot of characters (can be 8000 and more...). The string returned from WS is a string that ends with CRLF; values are separated with | and records are separated with § (can be this ASCII Characters a problem??). Something like this (this example has only one record)

80643|882168|145|1|3|1|0|0|0|0|0|2016-04-04 19:43:24|1900-01-01 00:00:00|1900-01-01 00:00:00|1900-01-01 00:00:00|2016-04-04 19:43:42|||||2016-04-04 09:45:42|08:45 1TG GALDINO,8 Milano Ditta:ZEBRE X PROVA ()||Int.pr: Orario Continuato|2016-04-04 10:45:42|V LARGA, Ditta: ()|LARGA|Int.co: Orario Continuato||0|2016-04-04 08:46:03|2016-04-04 19:43:42|2||0|0000-00-00 00:00:00§

When the Block occours, in my log I see **"lsp_r2: inizio a leggere"** (the row before the ReadToEnd) and I don't see **lsp_r2: terminato di leggere** (The row AFTER the ReadToEnd).

I have tried also using something like this

```
int totCar = 0;
while (sr.EndOfStream == false) {
    int numCar = sr.Peek();

    char[] caratteri = new char[numCar];

    sr.Read(caratteri, 0, numCar);

    string newString = new string(caratteri);
    // Arrivano un sacco di null.. li rimuovo
    int posNull = newString.IndexOf('\0');
    if (posNull >= 0)
        newString = newString.Substring(0, posNull);

    s += newString;
    totCar += newString.Length;

  //  if (isProblema)
  //      _logger.Info("lsp_r2: letti: " + numCar + " caratteri");

}
```

But I have had problem also using **sr.Read**

There is something I don't know about Socket Communication that can block the **Read**? Should I use a **ReadLine** because the line ends with CRLF? Do I have to use some other methods?

Sorry for my english. Let me know if I must give some other informations.

TIA

Alessandro

Comment: Not only the request/read can block, even asynchronous WebRequest may fail. The root cause can be a disconnected network and many others (you need to analyses network traces and server event logs). I would put your code in a new thread, then use thread.join after your timeout to test if the thread has finished. If it the request did not success, you may re-try the thread.

Comment: Thanks @josef have you an example how to implement this? Which timeout are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unchecked code snippet on how to do this with a thread and external timeout (second thread):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;

public class myWebRequest:IDisposable{
    public class myEventArgs:System.EventArgs{
        public string msg;
        public myEventArgs(string s){
            msg=s;
        }
    }
    public delegate void myDelegate (myEventArgs args);

        public myDelegate theDelegate;

        void onUpdate (myEventArgs arg)
        {
            if (theDelegate != null)
                theDelegate (arg);
        }

        Thread myThread = null;
        Thread watchThread = null;

    object lockObject = new object ();
    bool bThreadRunning = false;

    public myWebRequest(){
    }
    public void Dispose(){
        if (watchThread != null) {
            watchThread.Abort ();
            watchThread = null;
        }
        if (myThread != null) {
            myThread.Abort ();
            myThread = null;
        }
    }

    public void startRequest(){
        if (myThread != null) {
            myThread.Abort ();
            myThread = null;
        }
        myThread = new Thread (theThread);
        myThread.Start ();

        //start the watch thread
        if (watchThread != null) {
            watchThread.Abort ();
            watchThread = null;
        }
        watchThread = new Thread (theWatchThread);
        watchThread.Start ();
    }

    void theWatchThread(){
        try{
            Thread.Sleep (5000);
            if (bThreadRunning && myThread != null) {
                //thread is running, try a join
                if (myThread.Join (5000)) {
                    //join did work, although thread should have finished
                    myThread.Abort ();
                    myThread = null;
                    bThreadRunning = false;
                    onUpdate(new myEventArgs("failed"));
                }
            }
        }catch(ThreadAbortException ex){
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        }
    }

    void theThread(){
        string sMsg = "";
        try {
            bThreadRunning=true;
            //call the possibly blocking function
            sMsg=myWebRequest.CallWebServiceProblem("url", 4000);
            onUpdate(new myEventArgs(sMsg));
        }catch(ThreadAbortException ex){

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        bThreadRunning = false;
    }

    static string CallWebServiceProblem(string url, int timeout)
    {

        string s = "";

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;


        _logger.Trace("web service: {0} timeout: {1}", url, timeout);
        HttpWebRequest wrGETURL = null;
        try
        {
            bool isProblema = url.IndexOf("lsp_r2") >= 0;
            if (isProblema)
                _logger.Info("Sono in lsp_r2...");

            wrGETURL = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            wrGETURL.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            wrGETURL.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000; // Per vedere se sistema un po' i timeout...
            if (timeout != 0)
                wrGETURL.Timeout = 3000; // timeout...

            Stream ojstream = null;
            StreamReader sr = null;
            HttpWebResponse httpresponse = null;

            try
            {
                if (isProblema)
                    _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Chiamo GetResponse...");

                httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrGETURL.GetResponse();

                if (isProblema)
                    _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Chiamo GetResponseStream...");

                ojstream = httpresponse.GetResponseStream();
                Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

                if (isProblema)
                    _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Chiamo StreamReader...");

                sr = new StreamReader(ojstream, encode);

                if (isProblema)
                    _logger.Info("lsp_r2: inizio a leggere");

                s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (isProblema)
                {
                    _logger.Info("lsp_r2: terminato di leggere " + s.Length + " caratteri");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lsp_r2: terminato di leggere " + s.Length + " caratteri");
                    #if DEBUG
                    // _logger.Info("lsp_r2: ho letto " + s);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("lsp_r2: ho letto " + s);
                    #endif
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("web service: {0} timeout: {1} exception: {2} - {3}", url, timeout, ex.Message, ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "??");
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

                if (isProblema)
                    _logger.Info("lsp_r2: Concludo...");

                if (sr != null)
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    sr.Dispose();
                }

                if (ojstream != null)
                {
                    ojstream.Close();
                    ojstream.Dispose();
                }

                if (httpresponse != null)
                {
                    httpresponse.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

        return s;

    }
}
```

To use it from a form:

```
    void doTest(){
        myWebRequest theRequest = new myWebRequest ();
        theRequest.theDelegate += new myWebRequest.myDelegate (onReceive);
    }
    void onReceive(myWebRequest.myEventArgs args){
        //updateGUI?
    }
```

In onReceive you will get either "failed" or the result.

The above code is only a skeleton...

Comment: Thanks @josef I'll do some test. There isn't a simpler method to add a timeout to ReadToEnd?

Comment: The issue is that the API is faulty and does not always timeout. So the workaround is hard. Even with an async code change you may run in such issues.